# How to loop over data from a data-sly-use call

Tags: java, adobe, aem, sightly

I have data that I'm getting back from a data-sly-use call and I'm trying to loop over it using a data-sly-list call. This is currently what I have for code

```
<div data-sly-use.info="GetInformation" data-sly-unwrap></div>

<ul data-sly-list.test="${info.tests}">
    <li>${test.name}</li>
</ul>
```

***Tests*** is an Array List that gets returned from the use call.

Comment: Could you post what gets rendered? What is the type of tests? An array list of what?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are on the right track. Here is what I have:

**helloworld.html**

```
<sly data-sly-use.info="GetInformation"/>
<ul data-sly-list.test="${info.tests}">
    <li>${test.name}</li>
</ul>
```

**Note**: the `<sly>` element auto-unwraps and does not render in the HTML, so I used it to replace your empty `<div>`. More info [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/block-statements.html#sly-element).

**GetInformation.java**

```
package apps.wknd.components.content.helloworld;

import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GetInformation extends WCMUsePojo {

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        //noop
    }

    public List<Test> getTests() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Test("test1"), new Test("test2"), new Test("test3"));
    }

    public class Test {

        private String name;

        public Test(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**DOM:**

[image]

**Suggestions:**

If you are having trouble with your code I suspect it may be on the Java side, not in HTL. Here are some things to look out for:

- Is your Java file properly located at the same level as your HTL file?
- Does your Java class have a `getTests()` method?
- Does your Java class extend WCMUsePojo?

Answer (score 0):

You could have done a simple Google search for this. It took me [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/block-statements.html)

Here's an example

```
<dl data-sly-list="${currentPage.listChildren}">
    <dt>index: ${itemList.index}</dt>
    <dd>value: ${item.title}</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I've seen that but I can't see how it relates to using both a use call and a list call.